# Tricky object serialization

Tags: java

What is the safest way to serialize any kind of Java Object such that when:

```
DBObject obj = getFromDB;
Object id = obj.get(ID_KEY);
String s1 = safeSerialize(id);
```

The `obj.get(ID_KEY)` method returns an object that serves as an "id", it could be a ObjectId, String, Long, Integer, or anyt kind of Object.

Then do the same thing:

```
DBObject obj = getFromDB;
Object id = obj.get(ID_KEY);
String s2 = safeSerialize(id);
```

I need to make sure the `s1` is still equals to `s2`. I mean, for example `obj.get()` method might return new instance of say, `new Integer(100)` for a given `ID_KEY`, still having a "serialized" version.

Comment: One idea I'm thinking for this, is similar to "deep cloning" where all fields and inner fields are serialized, although I am not sure to what extent this idea can apply.

Comment: Serialization is *not* meant for long term persistence. I would strongly suggest a redesign.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to serialize after retrieving _from_ the database?  I usually see it used before _writing to_ the data store (not typically an actual database, though).  It reads like you just want `.equals()` to work, but you mention serializing repeatedly.

Comment: @StevenHood I'm trying to implement a way to store objects directly to the database, not really serialize after retrieving from DB, what I do is to deserialize stuff I get from DB. BTW, I managed to serialize just about any java object and deserialize it.

Comment: @Perception Like I said just now I managed to serialize a java.lang.Object properly to a DB and then deserialize it back as Object at runtime

Comment: @xkm - I didnt say it was technically impossible to do, I am saying that its a really bad idea. Unless you are telling me you know beforehand, for every single object that might make its way into a key, that 1. They have a proper serialVersionUUID defined. 2. They will never change, then you are just playing with fire. The first time a developer changes an object signature without knowing its impact all keys in the database that were serialized with the old version of the object will fail to deserialize.

Comment: @xkm, so the example you gave doesn't communicate that need.  Serializing to a store, and then deserializing from a store is a legitimate need.  However, expecting those two objects to be perfectly equal before and after is probably not realistic.  Code will change, classes will gain/lose properties, and you have to design for that.  If you think Java serialization is worth pursuing, read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html.  I think you want something else (JSON, XML) that's potentially more flexible and less coupled to object types.

Comment: I'll also add that your choice is also influence by the type of queries you need to perform.  None of these options allows you to query by any property inside this object, which makes me think you're implementing key-value storage.  You may have other properties associated with these objects that are stored in separate columns and able to be queried.  A hybrid approach is difficult to judge, but is usually painful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Java serialization gives you these guarantees:

- It certainly doesn't if any on the classes involve could change.
- It certainly doesn't if you serialize / deserialize on different JVM version/release/vendor platforms.
- It possibly doesn't for any class that has custom writeObject / readObject methods ... and that includes some of the basic types in java.util, etcetera.

JSON is as bad, if not worse.  The order of the attributes of JSON objects is explicitly undefined, so you have no guarantees that the attributes will appear in the serialization in the same order each time.

Binding based serial/deserializers for POJOs as XML could work (if they don't use attributes), but you need to beware of how a binding handles the serialization of inherently unordered collections such as HashSets and HashMaps.  The chances are that the order of the set/map members in the serialization won't be predictable.

---

My advice would be to think of another way to solve your actual problem ... whatever it is.

Comment: XML does not guarantee sibling order any more than JSON does, not for attributes and not for elements.

Comment: I see, so there is no machine independent way of serializing an object, i guess i might need to rethink my solution

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - You are right about attributes, but not elements.  Element order in XML is part of the information model.

Comment: @StephenC No you are wrong; it isn't guaranteed in the XML specifications that elements at the same level are not guaranteed to be returned in any specific order by the specifications, if they are returned in a consistent order it is an implementation detail of the parser.[The first thing to be aware of, and which might surprise you, is that the XML 1.0 specification itself does not guarantee element order in the sections on well-formedness (the sections on validity are more relevant to the discussion later in this article).](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-eleord/index.html)

Comment: @StephenC I managed to make this possible, to serialize any kind of Java object into the DB and deserialize it back to its type. Like: `db.put("thecar", serialize(car));` then later do: `Car car = db.get("thecar");` And if I put a object type of `Truck` then when I do a `get` on the same interface it will return a `Truck` instance

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - The document you linked to goes on to say that 1) virtually every parser *does* preserve order, and 2) many things (e.g. standards) built on top of the base XML specification specify / preserve order and presumably would break if the underlying XML parser did not preserve order.  **IN PRACTICE** ... XML document element order is stable.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - By contrast, JSON is not order preserving in practice because typical JSON parsers use hashes to represent objects.

Comment: @xkm - Yea, sure it is possible for simple examples.  But you try doing the same thing with complicated objects, with changing classes and across multiple JVM platforms.  That's when you are likely to see breakages.  That's why it is NOT SAFE.  (And you did ask for the "safest" solution.)

Comment: I would not rely on the serialization order of either XML or JSON to judge their suitability of serializing key objects. The more important consideration is the ability to retain the core identity when deserializing the data to an updated/changed version of the object. This normally comes down to having proper and consistent implementation of the `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because java.lang.Object is not serializable.

Classes are marked with java.io.Serializable to indicate that the programmer has allowed for binary representations to be able to reanimated.

Even if you were to require that the object that you were storing was limited to a given set of objects which were serializable, you'd be subject to the usual fragility of serialization.

If you limited the set of objects to a set for which you then provided custom serialization (as opposed to using the default serialization), you could then make it work.